# SearchPhaseExecutionException in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

[image]"

I am using Elasticsearch 1.7.5 
After create index name "`geo_ip`" I use java snippet code belows in order to search field `country` with the name `Turkey`.

```
 String index = "geo_ip";
        String type = "ip";
        String field = "country";
        String value = "Turkey";
        Map<String, String> query = new HashMap<>();
        query.put(field, value);
        // create client
        TransportClient client = EsLoading.settingElasticSearch();
        // searching
        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index)
                .setTypes(type)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
                .setQuery(query)
                .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

        SearchHit[] result = response.getHits().getHits();
        System.out.println("Current result: "+result.length);
```

But after that, it has problem like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[uVH-OgzjQfuUV8Bg_nViHQ][geo_ip][0]: SearchParseException[[geo_ip][0]: from[0],size[60]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":60,"query":{"country":"Turkey"},"explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[geo_ip] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[uVH-OgzjQfuUV8Bg_nViHQ][geo_ip][1]: SearchParseException[[geo_ip][1]: from[0],size[60]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":60,"query":{"country":"Turkey"},"explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[geo_ip] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[uVH-OgzjQfuUV8Bg_nViHQ][geo_ip][2]: SearchParseException[[geo_ip][2]: from[0],size[60]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":60,"query":{"country":"Turkey"},"explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[geo_ip] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[uVH-OgzjQfuUV8Bg_nViHQ][geo_ip][3]: SearchParseException[[geo_ip][3]: from[0],size[60]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":60,"query":{"country":"Turkey"},"explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[geo_ip] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[uVH-OgzjQfuUV8Bg_nViHQ][geo_ip][4]: SearchParseException[[geo_ip][4]: from[0],size[60]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":60,"query":{"country":"Turkey"},"explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[geo_ip] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:237)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$1.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:183)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:565)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help me to get around this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `country` field is probably analyzed, so you need to query with  lowercase `turkey`. Try this instead:

```
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index)
            .setTypes(type)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("country", "turkey"))
            .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

Or use a `match` query (with either `turkey` or `Turkey`) like this:

```
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index)
            .setTypes(type)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("country", "Turkey"))
            .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

Comment: Can you show me the diffirent between analyzed and not-analyzed. Thanks

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532648/analyzed-or-not-analyzed-what-to-choose

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `Java Api` to build a query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.7/search.html

Your query is also wrong. You should specify a query type like `term`:

```
{
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 60,
    "query" :
    {
        "term" :
        {
            "country" : "Turkey"
        }
    },
    "explain" : true
}
```

Comment: I use your sugesstion.
 SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index)
                .setTypes(type)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("country", "Turkey"))
                .setFrom(0).setSize(10000).setExplain(true)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

But it print out length of the "respond" is zero.  I think I not work well

Comment: What is the result of "curl -XGET host:9200/_cat/shards"?