# Elasticsearch Sort Order

Tags: elasticsearch

Im having trouble getting sort to work correctly in my query. I have tried a very simple example and get some unexpected results.

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": "name"
}
```

The result is that the names with numbers in come higher than those without. For example `Eurosport 1` will come before `Animal Planet`.

```
"sort": [
  "1"
]
```

and

```
"sort": [
  "a"
]
```

Is whats returned for each respectively.

Do I need something extra to have sort treat the fields as strings for sorting?

I can post more of the responses if its relevant.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like elastic search behaves differently depending on if the field's index is analyzed or not_analyzed. In my case it was analyzed so it was treating "Eurosport 1" as two words due to the whitespace and sorting on that.

see [analyzed or not_analyzed, what to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532648/analyzed-or-not-analyzed-what-to-choose)